# How to display the value from 2 'sourceColumns' - Google bar chart

Tags: html, google-visualization

I am trying to display the label name and the value of the column, in the column of a Google bar chart.

This is the code I am currently using to display the name of the label in the chart:

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0, 1,
            { calc: "stringify",
            sourceColumn: 0,
            type: "string",
            role: "annotation" },
2]);
```

I can get the value to display in the column by changing the 'sourceColumn' value to 1, but I cant get both.

So far I've tried

```
[0, 1]
0, 1
0 1
0 + 1
```

Can anyone suggest how I could possibly achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

the calculated column in the view is using a predefined function --> `"stringify"`

instead, you can provide your own function, to pull the values needed...

the `calc` function takes two arguments

```
function (dataTable, rowIndex) {}
```

1) data table used to create the view
2) row index being calculated

use the arguments to pull values from the data table row for any column
(`sourceColumn` isn't required)

the function should `return` the same type as defined in the column definition
`type: "string"`

in set columns ...

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1, {
  calc: function (dataTable, rowIndex) {
    var xAxisValue = dataTable.getValue(rowIndex, 0);
    var yAxisValue = dataTable.getValue(rowIndex, 1);
    return xAxisValue + ' = ' + yAxisValue;
  },
  type: "string",
  role: "annotation"
}, 2]);
```